# convertir un string en un jsonArray y obtener los valores en Delphi XE4

Tags: json, angular, delphi

una aplicación cliente me envía el siguiente string:

```json
{"tabla":"programacxp","opcion":"1","data":[{"fechapago":"2020-07-17","semana":29,"concepto":"RECOLECCION DE BASURA ","proyecto":"7E313-C2732","importe":"100.00","proved":"DDF","status":true,"clasif":"GASTO DE ADMON","periodo":"0","dias":"5","aplicado":false}]},
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo extraer los valores `tabla` y `opcion` y crear un *array* con el objeto `data`, para manipular esta información en Delphi XE?
El cliente me envía

```js
    modDb(jsonquery){
        let query = JSON.stringify(jsonquery);  
        let consulta = this.locUrl+'updDb/('+query+')';
        return this._http.get(consulta).pipe(map(res =>res));
```

haciendo debug en mi Aplicación Delphi, los datos llegan sin problema

```json
{"tabla":"programacxp","opcion":"1","data":[{"fechapago":"2020-07-17","semana":29,"concepto":"RECOLECCION DE BASURA ","proyecto":"7E313-C2732","importe":"100.00","proved":"DDF","status":true,"clasif":"GASTO DE ADMON","periodo":"0","dias":"5","aplicado":false}]}
```

Ahora mi problema es como manipularlos.

Gracias de nuevo por su valiosa ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte del soporte estándar de Delphi para *JSON*, que se encuentra en las unidades [`System.JSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.JSON).

Lo básico es *parsear* el string que obtienes en un objeto de tipo [`TJSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue), del que puedes ya extraer los valores mediante el método `GetValue`.

Te muestro primero un ejemplo simple (sin encargarnos aún del arreglo):

```
uses 
  System.JSON;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sJSON: string;
  Datos: TJSONValue;
  Tabla: string;
  Opcion: Integer;
begin
  { la cadena con el JSON de tu pregunta }
  sJSON := '{"tabla":"programacxp","opcion":"1","data":[{"fechapago":"2020-07-17"'
    + ',"semana":29,"concepto":"RECOLECCION DE BASURA ","proyecto":"7E313-C2732"'
    + ',"importe":"100.00","proved":"DDF","status":true,"clasif":"GASTO DE ADMON"'
    + ',"periodo":"0","dias":"5","aplicado":false}]}';
  { _conversión_ de la cadena en un TJSONValue }
  Datos := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(sJSON);
  { extracción de datos en variables de distintos tipos }
  Tabla := Datos.GetValue<string>('tabla');
  Opcion := Datos.GetValue<Integer>('opcion');
  { Mostrar datos al usuario }
  ShowMessage(Format(''
    + 'Tabla: %s'#13
    + 'Opcion: %d'
    , [Tabla, Opcion]));
end;
```

El arreglo lo podemos manejar de varias formas, una es valiéndonos del tipo [`TJSONArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray), lo que nos permite iterar por el arreglo y tratar a cada uno de sus elementos como un `TJSONValue`.

Básicamente algo como:

```
var
  ...
  DatosData: TJSONArray;
  DataElemento: TJSONValue;

begin
  ...
  { obtenemos el arreglo 'data' en el objeto DatosData, de tipo TJSONArray }
  DatosData := Datos.GetValue<TJSONArray>('data');
  for DataElemento in DatosData do
  begin
    { acá puedes utilizar DataElemento.GetValue para extraer los datos de cada elemento }
  end;
```

Poniendo todo en conjunto, podríamos agregar los datos de todos los elementos del arreglo al mensaje mostrado al usuario del primer ejemplo así:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sJSON: string;
  Datos: TJSONValue;
  Tabla: string;
  Opcion: Integer;
  DatosData: TJSONArray;
  DataElemento: TJSONValue;
  sData: string;
  Contador: Integer;
begin
  sJSON := '{"tabla":"programacxp","opcion":"1","data":[{"fechapago":"2020-07-17"'
    + ',"semana":29,"concepto":"RECOLECCION DE BASURA ","proyecto":"7E313-C2732"'
    + ',"importe":"100.00","proved":"DDF","status":true,"clasif":"GASTO DE ADMON"'
    + ',"periodo":"0","dias":"5","aplicado":false}]}';
  Datos := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(sJSON);
  Tabla := Datos.GetValue<string>('tabla');
  Opcion := Datos.GetValue<Integer>('opcion');
  DatosData := Datos.GetValue<TJSONArray>('data');
  sData := '';
  Contador := 0;
  for DataElemento in DatosData do
  begin
    sData := sData + Format(''
      + '   Elemento # %d '#13
      + '      FechaPago: %s'#13
      + '      Semana: %d'#13
      + '      Proyecto: %s'#13
      , [  Contador
         , DateToStr(DataElemento.GetValue<TDate>('fechapago'))
         , DataElemento.GetValue<Integer>('semana')
         , DataElemento.GetValue<string>('proyecto')
      ]);
    Inc(Contador);
  end;

  ShowMessage(Format(''
    + 'Tabla: %s'#13
    + 'Opcion: %d'#13
    + 'Data:'#13
    + '%s'
    , [Tabla, Opcion, sData]));
end;
```

Otra forma de obtener los datos es indicar la ruta completa en el método `GetData` sobre el `TJSONValue` que contiene todo el objeto, por ejemplo:

```
var
  ...
  FechaPago: TDate;
begin
  ...
  FechaPago := Datos.GetValue<TDate>('data[0].fechapago');
  ShowMessage(DateToStr(FechaPago));
end;
```

Para finalizar mencionar que hay otras bibliotecas que ofrecen soporte para procesar *JSON*, en lo personal trato de utilizar la RTL, pues el código es más estándar y tiene menos dependencias, pero al final puede haber alguna buena razón para utilizar una biblioteca de terceros y tampoco hay que cerrarse a la idea.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, solo tengo un problema: cuando  utilizo el método Tabla := Datos.GetValue<string>('tabla'); me genera un error "TJsonValue not contain a member named "GetValue"

Comment: por otro lado al intentar agregar en el USE system.JSON, no existe probablemente se deba a que uso Delphi XE 4

Comment: @hugo, por lo que puedo ver, en XE4, los tipos están declarados en la unidad DBXJSON. En ese entonces, la propiedad `Value` te devuelve el valor como string _cuándo es apropiado_, según [la documentación](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONAncestor.Value). Veo que en ese entonces existían los tipos `TJSONString`, `TJSONNumber`, derivados de `TJSONValue`. Lamentablemente no tengo XE4 a mano para escribir el código y probarlo. Espero que con lo que comento puedas orientarte.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, logré obtener la información con este código:

```
function TServerMethods1.updDb(datos: string): string;
var
  nomTabla, DataStr, fieldStr, parStr, nomfield, mensaje: string;
  j, x, opc, lenStr, lenTag: integer;
  LJsonObj, DataObj: TJSONObject;
  jsPairTabla, jsPairOpcion, jsPairData: TjsonPair;
  jsonData, jsOpcion, PairValue: TJSONValue;
  currTable: TADTable;
  AField: array [0 .. 20] of array [0 .. 1] of string;
  fs: TFormatSettings;
 currField: tField;
begin
  // jsonString := datos; // solo para debuguear....
  LJsonObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(datos) as TJSONObject;
  try
    jsonData := LJsonObj.Get('tabla').JsonValue;
    jsPairTabla := TjsonPair(jsonData);
    nomTabla := jsPairTabla.jsonString.ToString;
    jsOpcion := LJsonObj.Get('opcion').JsonValue;
    jsPairOpcion := TjsonPair(jsOpcion);
    opc := StrToInt(jsPairOpcion.jsonString.ToString);
    DataStr := LJsonObj.Get('data').JsonValue.ToString;
    lenStr := Length(DataStr) - 2;
    fieldStr := DataStr.Substring(1, lenStr);
    DataObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(fieldStr) as TJSONObject;
    PairValue := TJSONValue.Create;
    for j := 0 to DataObj.Size - 1 do
    begin
      PairValue := DataObj.Get(j).JsonValue;
      parStr := DataObj.Get(j).ToString;
      jsPairData := TjsonPair(PairValue);
      lenTag := Ansipos('":', parStr);
      AField[j, 0] := copy(parStr, 1, lenTag);
      if pos('":true', parStr) > 0 then
        AField[j, 1] := 'true'
      else if pos('":false', parStr) > 0 then
        AField[j, 1] := 'false'
      else
        AField[j, 1] := jsPairData.jsonString.ToString;
    end;
  finally
    currTable := TADTable.Create(self);
    currTable := programaCxp;
         // aquí proceso la información
         //
  end;
end;
```

Obviamente no es la solución optima, pero tanto JsonVAlue.value, como JsonString.value, para obtener el nombre y el valor del par no funcionan en XE4,
Saludos